# Adding comments for columns to a view in Athena (Presto)

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

After creating a view in Athena (Presto), I would like to add a comment for each column and also a comment for the view itself. Looking at the AWS official documentation, I can't find any reference for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, its not possible at this point. Even if you add comments while creating View, it'll be removed right after view is created. An alternative would be to create a reference table containing table, column and comments information.